# Can I compress the glb file using the draco encoder with node.js?

Tags: node.js, three.js, gltf

I upload an `obj` file and convert it to a `glb` file on `three.js`. So I wanted to compress the file using the `Draco encoder`, but I only knew how to compress it using `cmd`. Is there any way to compress using `node.js`?

edited

I solved it by myself. The method was simple. I'm just install [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gltf-pipeline?activeTab=readme).
And, my code is here.

```
const gltfPipeline = require('gltf-pipeline');
const fsExtra = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');
const glbToGltf = gltfPipeline.glbToGltf;
const processGltf = gltfPipeline.processGltf;

const glb = fsExtra.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname+'/../public/glbFiles/' + req.filename));
const options = {
  dracoOptions: {
    compressionLevel: 10
  }
};
glbToGltf(glb)
  .then(gltf => {
    processGltf(gltf.gltf, options)
        .then(results => {
          fsExtra.writeJsonSync(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../public/compressionFiles/' + req.filename.split('.')[0] + '.gltf'), results.gltf);
        });
  });
```

I hope you can solve this problem as well. Go for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draco3d)

or

Convert [DRACOExporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/misc_exporter_draco.html) from [/examples/js/exporters](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/exporters/DracoExporter.js) to a module